# Strongly measurable functions are weakly measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

From  [Pettis measurability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_measurable_function), if $f:X\to B$ is a function on a measure space$(X,\Sigma,\mu)$  taking values in a Banach space $B$, then $f$ strongly measurable should imply $f$ weakly measurable.

$f$ strongly measurable means that there exist a sequence of simple functions $(f_n)$ converging almost everwhere to $f$. If $g\in B^*$, with $B^*$ denoting the continuous dual of $B$, then $(g\circ f_n)$ is a sequence of measurable functions converging almost everywhere to $g\circ f$.

But in general the almost everywhere limit of a sequence measurable functions is not measurable unless the measure space is complete.

Am I missing something? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Ramiro Yes but metric completeness is not the same as measure completeness ?

Comment: @Ramiro Ok so there is an issue right? Or did I misunderstood to definition of weak measurability?

Comment: Actually, there is an issue with the definition of strong measurability.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a small "issue" with the definition of strong measurability for non-complete measure spaces.

To see it take the Banach space to be $\Bbb R$. Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ to be a measure space that is **not** complete.

Then using the definition of strong measurability as "$f$ strongly measurable means that there exists a sequence of simple functions $(f_n)$ converging almost everwhere to $f$" will result in having non-measurable functions that will be "strong measurable".

However, given any such strong measurable function $h$ that is non-measurable, there is a measurable function $k$ such that $k=h$ a.e. (and of course, $k$ is also strong measurable).

**Remark**  In fact, strong measurability is not defined for individual functions $f$ but for the class $[f]$ (class of functions $h$ such that $h=f$ a.e.).

It is similar to what happens with $L^p$. We say that a function is in $L^p$, but to be precise the elements of $L^p$ are equivalence classes of functions by relation $=$ a.e.. For a function $f$, we may write $f \in L^p$, to actually mean $[f] \in L^p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the right definition of weak measurability here would be $f=f'$ a.e. for some weakly measurable function $f'$? On the Wikipedia page there were no mention of complete measure space...

Comment: I also had a basic question relating to measurability here : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4087241/522332. Do you you think you could have a look at it? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Alphie , the "issue" is not in the definition of weak measurability itself, but in the fact that strong measurability is actually defined for the class of function module $=$ a.e..

Comment: Right but the definition of weak measurability is $g\circ f$ measurable for all $g\in B^*$, and for this definition to make sense we need $f$ to be a function (not a class of functions). If I define $\tilde{f}(x)$ to be equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ outside a null set and $0$ otherwise, then I obtain a $\Sigma-\mathcal{B}(B)$ measurable function (also weakly measurable) with $\tilde{f}=f$ a.e. no?

Comment: @Alphie , Yes. Exactly.